# Google App Engine (GAE) cron url: url?keyword=abc

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I would like to run cron job on GAE and using python

In the cron.yaml, how do i insert the "url" field if consist of some "get" info

The:

- description: whatever

  url: url?keyword=a

  schedule: every day 15:00

give me error when deploy

Comment: What kind of url are you using?
What kind error you get?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following `cron.yaml` and it worked fine. At least on the dev_appserver:

```
cron:
- description: url test
  url: /tasks?keyword=test
  schedule: every day 15:00
```